# Qt 4.8 - Application Run Time Error Side by Side

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2008, runtime, side-by-side

I have a question regarding a run-time error of side by side.

I'm a Qt developer using verion Qt 4.8 together with VS2008.

I have an application. When I compiled it as a debug, it compiles and runs fine.
It also runs fine when I compile it as release build after I putting in the `*.exe` folder all the necessary Qt DLLs' which the app is using.

The problem is that when I run this release built app exe-file together with the necessary DLLs I get the following error message:

> The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail.

I run the application file in the Dependency Walker Application I got

> Error opening file. The system cannot find the file specified (2). in the following files:

```
API-MS-WIN-CORE-COM-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ERROR-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ROBUFFER-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-STRING-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-SCALING-L1-1-0.DLL
DCOMP.DLL
IESHIMS.DLL
```

How this issue can be solved?

Thank you in Advance,

Sincerely Yours,

Eyal N.

Comment: Any updates? as I'm facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29

You need to install the correct MS redistributables when you deploy your application.  This should fix some of the dependency errors.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/deployment-windows.html#visual-studio-2008-and-manual-installs

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/deployment-windows.html#application-dependencies

Hope that helps.

Comment: Have you tried running dependency walker while it is running from inside Qt Creator or MSVS?  If it isn't running outside your development environment, running depends.exe on it won't help.